# Make region /state optional in customer address in adminhtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I managed to make the region / state dropdown optional in the frontend without any problems. In the backend however, I did not make it work. So how could I make the state / region dropdown optional in the customer address area?

Thanks!

**Magento 1.9**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to `admin panel -> system -> configuration -> general -> state options -> State is required for`

and `Display not required State -> yes`

remove your country from the dropdown to make it optional from frontend side

https://belvg.com/blog/best-way-to-removedisable-statesprovince-field-for-specific-countries-in-magento.html

Comment: It works on the frontend, I need it optional in the backend. The setting you mentioned does not work for the backend.

Comment: try to clear the cache it should work for all places, remove all countries from an above-mentioned location which country' state you need optional

Comment: Yes! It worked :-)